# Image not resizing properly: image gets cut off when window is resized

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I at least got the following to render the image, but when the window is resized past a certain point: part of the image  gets cut off.

```
#header {
  background-image: image-url('my_header.png'); #image-url is a helper in rails
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: 100%;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
```

And then showing how I specify the image at the top of the body in `application.html.erb`:

```
<body>
   <div id="header"></div>
</body>
```

What I want to happen is for the image to scale proportionality  but not get cut off. I do not want any specific height set.  I want it to automatically scale as needed (however, I wasn't able to get the image to render unless I specified the height with `px`).

Comment: Have you tried background-size: cover;

Comment: @Pangloss I tried it just now and it was not working for me.

Comment: `image-url` is invalid, it should be `url`

Comment: @Pangloss I am using rails.  I'm not sure if image-url is a rails helper or not.

Comment: Which part is not working to you?

Comment: As I resize the window: after a certain point the bottom of the image gets too long for the specified height so it gets cut off.  I'd like it to take up as much height as it needs. I am using bootstrap if that matters.

Comment: That's the right behavior to maintain the aspect ratio, if you want to keep the image height always the same, what do you need for width, repeat? stretch? or any?

Comment: I do not need to keep the height the same.  I want it to be responsive and scale appropriately.  Width seems to be working fine.  In other words, I don't need the height locked in at 100px.

Comment: Do you need the image to cover the entire header?

Comment: @Pangloss oh the issue appears to be the width.  The height works fine.  The issue is that when the width of the window changes it cuts the image off at the bottom.

Comment: @Pangloss I want the entire image to always show.

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, only post the compiled CSS.  Also, you have to provide enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @cimmanon added more details. I'm not sure what more details I can add.

Comment: If you still couldn't find an answer, see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fpzzuj9q/).

Comment: @Pangloss 1000 times thank you!!! Please post as an answer so that I can give you credit.

Comment: Glad to hear that, no worries.

Comment: Why the down vote???

Comment: Not sure about the down vote, but I have a question, why don't you use the inline <img> directly instead of background? quick demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fpzzuj9q/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pangloss deserves recognition for providing a fantastic answer [at this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fpzzuj9q/) which he referenced in the comments.

Here is his css:

```
#header {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/zOZVQaf.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    border-radius: 1em;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#header img {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden; /*hidden but reserve the space*/
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

And the html:

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/zOZVQaf.jpg">
</div>
```

@Pangloss provided this answer in the comments.  If/when he posts an answer to this question, I will switch it over to his answer.